# Hide any values above 1

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am using the macro below to hide any values above 1. column 10 is written to compare two dates and hide any values for date differences above 1.

I originally wrote the function in column 10 as

```
=IF($G$1-I4>0, $G$1-I4,"0" )
```

I had to adjust it to

```
 =IF(I7="","",IFERROR($G$1-I7,""))
```

to correct for a calculation error with blank values.

The macro worked as expected before I adjusted the formula but now it hides all rows with the formula in column 10.

g1=todays date
i4= completion date if applicable

```vb
Sub HURows()
    BeginRow = 4
    EndRow = 600
    ChkCol = 10

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value > 1 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Autofilter?

```
Sub Filter()

    Rows("3:3").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<1", Operator:=xlAnd
    
End Sub
```

(I'm assuming row three is your header row)